# Show the result from query database php

Tags: php, mysql, echo

i have a code like this:

```
$genre = 'jazz';
$what_genre = mysql_real_escape_string($genre);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT song.id, song.title, genre.genre FROM song INNER JOIN genre ON song.id_genre=genre.id_genre WHERE genre.genre = '" .$what_genre. "' ORDER BY id");

if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)
{
    while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        echo $result['id'];
        echo $result['title'];
        echo $result['genre'];
    }
}
```

I want to show the result, but it failed. The system give me an error report:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

What should I do? Thanks for your help.

Comment: do `echo "SELECT song.id, song.title, genre.genre FROM song INNER JOIN genre ON song.id_genre=genre.id_genre WHERE genre.genre = '" .$topiknya. "' ORDER BY id"` and tell me what you get.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: Please use `mysql_error()` to display query fail http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your query from id to song.id like this

```
"SELECT song.id, song.title, genre.genre FROM song INNER JOIN genre ON song.id_genre=genre.id_genre WHERE genre.genre = '" .$topiknya. "' ORDER BY song.id";
```

Comment: What is your genre table id name it is id or id_genre?

Comment: it solved. Evidently I was wrong on column name. It should be `song.song_title`, not `song.title`. I don't see it carefully. :)

Answer (score 0):

in query where  `ORDER BY id` use `song.id` instead of `id`.